# What are in material3 tab layout still using material2 tab

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Im just starting using material3
and I finding component like tab in material documentation
but I didn't find component like tab in material2

how that material3 still using material2 tab?

or just put parent theme to material3 so it will automatically tab using material3 style?

sorry for my english
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a material2 tab layout (Bar) for material3.